# file size increasing and decreasing after cPickle using incremental classifier sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I am using the [PassiveAggressiveRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor.html) incremental classifier. Every time I use [partial_fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor.partial_fit) I save the model into a pickle file.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import time

X = np.array(range(1000))
y = np.array([x + random.random() for x in X])
X = X.reshape(1000,1)

model = linear_model.PassiveAggressiveRegressor()
model.partial_fit(X, y)
cPickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))


for i in range(0,10):
    time.sleep(1)
    model = cPickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
    model.partial_fit(X, y)
    cPickle.dump(model, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))
```

---

The thing that I don't get is why is the file model.pkl changing size. Sometimes it'
s size becomes 889 bytes then down to 886 bytes. Is that normal? it's doing its own stuff? or something is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be explained by the fact that the original pickle used some other protocol.

For example try specifying `protocol=2` as a keyword argument to the `pickle.dump` and test it again. So try to specify always the same protocol.

In general, binary pickle should be much smaller in size.

There are currently 3 different protocols which can be used for pickling.

1. Protocol version 0 is the original ASCII protocol and is backwards compatible with earlier versions of Python.
2. Protocol version 1 is the old binary format which is also compatible with earlier versions of Python.
3. Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides much more efficient pickling of new-style classes.